# Rendering React components from json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json object like:

```
let data = {
            UI: {
                "baseType":"App",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "baseType":"TextField",
                        "props":{

                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
```

I want to render it like:

```
<App>
 <TextField>
 </TextField>
```

So, I need to get dynamically rendered components from json object. For the same, I wrote a method:

```
getFromJson(obj) {
    // let Type = obj.baseType;

    let children = obj.children
        ? obj.children.map((obj) => {
                return this.getFromJson(obj,obj.baseType);
            })
        : '';
    // <></
    switch (obj.baseType) {
        case "App":

            return (
                <App key={key} {...obj.props}>
                    {children}
                </App>
            );
        case "TextField":
            //      {children}
            //  </TextField>);
            return (<TextField key={key} {...obj.props}>
                    {children}
                </TextField>
            );
        default:
            return <h1>Returning default case.</h1>;
    }

    // return <div>Hello</div>
}
```

I am calling the above method:

```
render() {

        let renderedUI = "";
        if (this.props.json.UI) {
            renderedUI = this.getFromJson(this.props.json.UI, "UI");
        }

        return renderedUI;
    }
```

The output is only App component, i.e., children are not getting rendered. The children although has value: `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: "TextField", ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: My whole component is:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "./TextField";
import App from "./App";

export default class RenderFromJson extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.getFromJson = this.getFromJson.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {}

    getFromJson(obj,key) {
        // let Type = obj.baseType;

        let children = obj.children
            ? obj.children.map((obj) => {
                    return this.getFromJson(obj,obj.baseType);
                })
            : '';
        // <></
        switch (obj.baseType) {
            case "App":

                return (
                    <App key={key} {...obj.props}>
                        {children}
                    </App>
                );
            case "TextField":
                //      {children}
                //  </TextField>);
                return (<TextField key={key} {...obj.props}>
                        {children}
                    </TextField>
                );
            default:
                return <h1>Returning default case.</h1>;
        }

        // return <div>Hello</div>
    }

    render() {

        let renderedUI = "";
        if (this.props.json.UI) {
            renderedUI = this.getFromJson(this.props.json.UI, "UI");
        }

        return renderedUI;
    }
}
```

TextField:

```
import React from "react";

export default class TextField extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }


    render() {
        console.log("returning from textfield");
        return <h1>Hi from textfield</h1>;
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import RenderFromJson from "./RenderFromJson";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {}

    render() {

        return <h2>In App</h2>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this: https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/

Comment: Thanks. But, that is a huge library. I am looking for answers related to my scenario.

Comment: It's not that big. Consider effort to learn a well tested implementation with lots of example other than try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: can you post `TextField` component?

Comment: @Ali Please have a look.

Comment: I had just copied your code and paste it in my editor and changed `TextField` to `span` and `App` to `div` it seems to work fine

Comment: That's not what I am willing to do. I am trying to return dynamic components.

Comment: Take a look at how it's done by `rjx` - https://github.com/repetere/rjx/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally after one hour I find the issue , your `App` component will get `children` array in `props` object and you must append the children inside your `App` component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>In App</h1>
            {this.props.children /* this what solve the issue */} 
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GetFromJson = ({ children }) => {
   return children.map(elem => {
       const Tag = elem.baseType
       const props = { elem }
       return (
          <Tag> ...props </Tag>
       )
   })
}
```

And then in your component

```
render(){
   return <GetFromJson children={this.props.json.UI.children} />
}
```

I am just wondering, what do you have in props ? because maybe we need to change the ...props

Comment: I can have nested children too. Your case handles only on level of children.

Comment: just make a condition that will return another map of your data if you have nested children, for example you check if you have the key children in props and if you do instead of return ...props in you <Tag> you return a map of props.children

Comment: This is what I have done in my original code, I think.

Comment: you only do a loop on the first children like i did, for now for testing purpose instead of returning <Tag> ...props </Tag>, do <Tag> !props.children ? ...props : null </Tag>

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have issue with binding,try this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.getFromJson = this.getFromJson.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Nope, same result.